How to split string by white spaces and special characters
I try to split string by white spaces and special characters using tf2. tf.strings.split can only split by one delimiter, while tf.strings.regex_replace is very slow. I feel it is very common needs, hence I wonder if there is more generic approach achieve it?
Example = "[Pheromone perfume that excites and seduces the opposite sex. Subtle, long-lasting perfume] Pheromone perfume, date, blind date, gift for use in entertainment, date recommended No. 1 men's perfume No. (1 men's perfume No. 1 pheromone perfume repurchase product)"


Can you give examples? In first tests, regex_replace was vastly faster for me.

Hi @user1269298,To deal with this, here you may use the TensorFlow functions and the tf. strings. The regex_split is a very special function for the Strings which allows user to define a concrete regular expression for the splitting of the Strings. It is also bounded to more than one delimiter can be easily dealt with in this approach.
